# IF Value to be show as currency which can also be added to a later sum calculation

Tags: excel

I have the following formula, however I would like to show 325, 125 and 0 as £325.00 etc which would also be recognized within a column of other no formatted cells which I could  calculate. At the moment all the number are recognized with the exception of the these.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("platform",E10)),"325",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ladders",E10)),"125", "0"))
```

Comment: Please clarify - what does your data look like, what values are you currently getting, and what values do you want?

Comment: Remove quotes around the numbers and apply currency format to the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you simply want the formula as-is, but want it recognized as a value by Excel (so you can perform mathematical calculations on it), you just need to change this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("platform",E10)),"325",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ladders",E10)),"125", "0"))
```

To this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("platform",E10)),325,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ladders",E10)),125, 0))
```

Note that without the "" around the numbers, the numbers are treated as values. Otherwise, they are treated as text. Now simply choose a number format as Currency.